# Access remote file contents as a stream using WinSCP .NET assembly

Tags: c#, winscp, winscp-net, azure-blob-storage

I am trying to open file to read from SFTP using WinSCP .NET assembly as par to my exercise to archive file from SFTP to Azure blob.

To upload a blob to Azure, I am using

```
using (var fileStream = inputStream)
{
    blockBlob.UploadFromStream(fileStream);
    blobUri = blockBlob.Uri.ToString();
}
```

How to get the stream from the file on SFTP server?

I managed using `SftpClient` to get the stream using the following code and it works but unfortunately not able to achieve the same using WinSCP .NET assembly.

```
sftpClient.OpenRead(file.FullName)
```

Can anyone help me how to achieve the same using WinSCP .NET assembly?

Because I need to connect to SFTP using username, password and privatekey I am using WinSCP .NET assembly.

Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The WinSCP .NET assembly supports providing the contents of a remote file using streams using the [`Session.GetFile` method](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/library_session_getfile):

```
using (Stream stream = session.GetFile("/path/file.ext"))
{
    blockBlob.UploadFromStream(stream);
}
```