# Upload byte array without actually creating a local file to SFTP server using WinSCP .NET assembly?

Tags: powershell, sftp, winscp, winscp-net

I need to write a PowerShell script that reads some data and writes it to a file on a remote SFTP location.  I'd rather not generate a local file first before initiating the SFTP session.  Can WinSCP work with a byte array to send to the remote folder?

Answer (score 0):

Use [`Session.PutFile` method](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/library_session_putfile) (available since WinSCP 5.19).

---

For a similar question (just for a download), see:
[Access remote file contents as a stream using WinSCP .NET assembly](https://stackoverflow.com/q/33014313/850848).